# AppDomain info from an assembly

Tags: c#

I am trying to get an AppDomain's info for one of my reference assemblies. I am aware of the fact that we can load an assembly at runtime and then get that assembly to run in a separate AppDomain which we create. But, in my case, there is a referred assembly (actually an AddIn) that runs in its own domain. Please let me know, if I can get a reference to an existing assembly and AppDomain for the referenced assembly using System.Reflection.Assembly and System.AppDomain or Similar classes?

Comment: When you state

> ..there is a referred assembly (actually an AddIn) that runs in its
> own domain.

How do you know it's using it's own domain exactly?

Comment: By calling ...MessageBox.Show("Current Domain is: " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);

Comment: @Jason...I need to get the AppDomain for the referenced assembly from calling assembly's method. Also, I have added the reference to the assemblies at compile time. Just as we can get the names of referenced Assemblies using System.Reflection.Assembly, I need to know if I can get the AppDomain, that assembly code is running in.